# How to know if a QTable is loaded

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, quasar-framework

Is there a specific event to know when a Quasar QTable has finished loading? I am doing some benchmark performance evaluation and want to know exactly when the table is rendered with all its rows. I don't see anything in the Quasar docs about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Vue Devtools Extension for Chrome and go to the 'Events' tab.
All the events from your components are listed there and probably your QTable events too.

If this doesn't work you can go to your node_modules component folder and search where it is mounted and create a custom event for your code like this:

```
    mounted(){
     this.$root.$emit('CustomEvent', this.customVar || true)
   }
```